# Why does this code result in different behavior on different machines?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

Apparently sometimes this code goes into an infinite loop, sometimes terminates or sometimes gets a segmentation fault depending on the machine. Why is the behavior inconsistent?

```
void loop() {
    int x[512]; 
    int i=0; 
    while (i++ <512) { 
        x[i] = 0; 
    } 
} 
int main () { 
    printf("\nCalling loop -->>\n"); 
    loop(); 
}
```

Comment: Imagine when `i` is 511.

Comment: but why doesn't crush sometimes?

Comment: ``while (i++ <512)`` this line is still blowing up my head.

Comment: Can't guarantee `x[512] = 0` trashes the value of i.

Comment: @cf16 Undefined behavior is just how it sounds.

Comment: It crashes sometimes because that's what happens when you have undefined behavior. Anything goes. (sing with me) It can work, it can crash, it can do the disco dance...

Comment: @NikBougalis: I say, we can crash where we want to, a place where they will never find. And we can act like we code from out of this world, and leave the core file far behind. And we can crash! (With apologies to the men in hats...)

Comment: Haha. That's *awesome*. I totally sang along and everyone in the office is looking at me weird!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are doing **post-increment**. When `i` is 511 it passes the inequality, but then it increments to 512. Assigning `x[512]` is **access violation** to memory that **might be** or **might be not** (it is **undefined**) owned by your application. As stated in comments, you experience a slightly different behavior on different platforms because this mistake results in so-called **undefined behavior**. In other words, the results of this (wrong) operation are not defined by the C++ standard. And since **different** compilers and operating systems have **different** underlying implementation - you get **different** behavior.

Comment: Actually, it is probably overwriting the value of `i` on the stack.

Comment: @EricJ.: It's just as likely that `i` is allocated *before* `x` in memory, or (as I just saw on my own system) that there's a gap between `x` and `i`.

Comment: @EricJ. - it depends on the compiler. Back about fifteen years ago, Microsoft had a sample program with essentially this problem, and it ran and produced correct output when it was compiled with their compiler. Compiling it with Borland's compiler produced a program that crashed. The difference was in the layout of the auto objects in memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you invoke undefined behaviour (as you do) you get undefined behaviour — which means that different compilers can give different results on the same machine, and different compilers on different machines can give different results; heck, a single compiler on a single machine can look at the phase of the moon and decide to do different things depending on that!  And they're all correct because undefined behaviour is exactly that — undefined.

If you get an infinite loop, the chances are that `&x[512] == &i` and when you write zero to `x[512]` (which is the undefined behaviour), you zero `i` and the loop continues.

If it crashes, the chances are that `x[512]` coincides with some crucial control information on the calling stack, and by trampling on the return address or frame pointer, you've completely screwed up the system.

But, regardless, the machine and compiler are working fine; your code is the problem.  Your loop should be:

```
while (i < 512)
    x[i++] = 0;
```